# PHP Loop through form values

Tags: php, forms, loops, foreach

I have a form that submits lots of small fields that I need to loop through and perform actions on.

The form looks like this:

```
<input class="" type="hidden" name="pid" value="10">
<input class="" type="hidden" name="date" value="01-01-2014">
```

Then around 100 - 200 of these...

```
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_12_2014-03-06" value="2" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_12_2014-03-07" value="2" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_12_2014-03-08" value="1" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_13_2014-03-06" value="3" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_13_2014-03-07" value="2" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_13_2014-03-08" value="4" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_14_2014-03-06" value="1" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_14_2014-03-07" value="2" size="1">
<input class="minnight" type="text" name="minnight_14_2014-03-08" value="2" size="1">
```

When the form is submitted, I need to loop through each "minnight" field, extract the "12_2014-03-06" into "12" and "2014-03-06", store them both in vars and finally do a database query before moving to the next one.

Any pointers on where I should start with this mess?

Comment: Yes. Start with trying something on your own, and then post the code.

Comment: take a look at foreach, http://br2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php ... then extract the data u need from the key

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Stackoverflow isn't for the community to tell you how to code, but to teach you how to code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the use of [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [POST variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Try something along the lines of:

```
// Loop over each item in the form.
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    // Split the name into an array on each underscore.
    $splitString = explode("_", $name);

    // If the data begins with "minnight", use it.
    if ($splitString[0] == "minnight") {
        // Set the other desired values into variables.
        $secondValue = $splitString[1];
        $thirdValue= $splitString[2];

        // Database query goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks prefect. I just came up with a nasty preg_match loop but yours looks much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over $_POST and read the values: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

```
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){
    // do something using key and value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also see the function explode()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php