# Updating MySQL table after submitting form with checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a web form.

The form is loading records from a MySQL database.

This is the form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="signupalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>Error:</p>   <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre" class="col-md-3 control-label">Marcas asociadas:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <?php 
                    global $mysqli;
                    $loop = m ysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tb_marcas_vendedor  LEFT JOIN tb_marcas  ON                                                       tb_marcas_vendedor.marca_vendedor = tb_marcas.id_marca
                                                    WHERE tb_marcas_vendedor.vendedor_marca =  '".$_SESSION[ 'id_usuario']. "' 
                                                    ORDER BY id_marca" ) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
                                                    while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($loop)) 
                                                    { 
                                                        if ($row[ 'seleccionado']==1 )
                                                        { 
                                                            echo "<label><input type='checkbox' value=".$row[ 'seleccionado']. " name='sport' checked> ".$row[ 'nombre_marca']. "</label>"; 
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        { 
                                                            echo "<label><input type='checkbox' value=".$row[ 'seleccionado']. " name='sport' > ".$row[ 'nombre_marca']. "</label>"; 
                                                        } 
                                                    } 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i>Actualizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php echo resultBlock($errors); ?>
</div>
```

And this is the output:

[image]
[image]

I need to update the mysql data. If the user checks a box,then the value for 
$row['seleccionado'] should be 1, if not checked, it should be 0.
How can I get the id from the selected row and update the table after submitting the form?

EDIT

This is the table tb_marcas_vendedor structure:

[image]

Comment: So your problem is the update function?

Comment: @jerome, my first problem is to identify each row. The table tb_marcas_vendedor  has following colums: id_marca_vendedor (unique index), marca_vendedor, vendedor_marca, seleccionado

Comment: Do the sport has a field too in your database?

Comment: The name on the input fields should have something like `name='sport_" . $row['id_marca_vendedor'] . "'"`.  If that's the unique index, you can use part of the name to identify what record to update in said database.

Comment: @jerome, no, it is just a given name. I have updated my question and included the data structure

Comment: @Froopy, i have updated my question including the table structure

Comment: HTML form submission - only checkboxes that are ticked are sent to the server for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input with the id in the hidden element, and a normal checkbox that just updates the hidden element using native JavaScript:

```
<input type='hidden' name='" . $row['id_marca_vendedor'] . "' value='" . $row[ 'seleccionado'] . "'><input type="checkbox" onclick='this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value'>
```

Make sure this is no space in between these elements.  This will ensure even unchecked values are accounted for.

If you append `id_marca_vendedor` to the name field on your input field, you can loop through the variables on the server side and get the results/id on the POST portion:

```
// Loop over each item in the form.
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

    // Get the id and value
    $id = $name;
    $selection = $_POST[$name];

    // Database query goes here

}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21168151/6871531)

Edit: Updated to include @jeff's point of unchecked values.

Comment: I have updated my code: name=".$row['id_marca_vendedor'].", no need for name='sport_" . $row['id_marca_vendedor'] . "'"

Comment: I am not updating updating with 0 at the start. You can see in the screenshots that there are only three rows with 0 value: Mini,Nissan and Volkswagen, all others has 1 at the start.

Comment: using your proposal, all records are set to 1

Comment: i have implemented your proposal: foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

                    // Get the id and value
                    $id = $name;
                    $selection = 1;
                    echo "**id=".$id." seleccion= ".$selection;
                    // Database query goes here, possibly appended with the update to zero query first.
                
                }

Comment: i have submitted the form as it is from start, with three not checked records

Comment: this is the echo output, from id=1 to id=80: **id=1 seleccion= 1**id=2 seleccion= 1...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166135/discussion-between-froopy-and-mvasco).