# How to insert student subject and grade into the database in a better way?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I am a beginner to php and am designing student information system where students need to enter 9 subject and its corresponding grade based on the number of sittings. Is there any better way to do this apart from what I have been doing?

These are my codes.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(select){
   if(select.value==2){
    document.getElementById('div2a').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('div2a').style.display = "none";
   }
} 
</script>
```

```css
<style>
    .striped-border {
        border: 1px solid #0d4115;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .form2a{
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
  <form name="register" method="POST" action="process2.php"  >
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Number of Sitting(s)</label>
 <select name="sitting" id="sitting" class="form-control" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>

                  
              </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="output1" id="div1" name="onesitting">
<div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>School Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="schoolname1" id="schoolname" class="form-control" placeholder="School Name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exam Type</label>
 <select name="examboard1" id="examboard" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value="">Exam Type</option>
                  <option value="WAEC">WAEC(SSCE)</option>
                  <option value="WAEC">WAEC(GCE)</option>
                  <option value="NECO">NECO(SSCE)</option>
                  <option value="NECO">NECO(GCE)</option>
                  <option value="NABTEB">NABTEB(SSCE)</option>
                  <option value="NABTEB">NABTEB(GCE)</option>
                  <option value="OTHERS">OTHERS</option>

              </select>
  </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exam Date</label>
  <?php
  $examyear = range(1960, 2050);
  ?>
   <select class="form-control" name="examdate1" id="examdate" placeholder="Exam Date">
     <option value="">Select date</option>
      <?php
      foreach($examyear as $examdate){
        echo '<option value= "' .$examdate.'">'.$examdate.'</option>';
      }
?>

   </select>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exam Number</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="examno1" id="examno" placeholder="Exam Number">

  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-borderless" id="example">
            <tr>
              <td width="12%"><label class="control-label">S/NO</label></td>
              <td width="53%"><label class="control-label">SUBJECTS</label></td>
              <td width="35%"><label class="control-label">GRADE</label></td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject11" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade11" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select</option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject12" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade12" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject13" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade13" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject14" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
                
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade14" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>
          <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject15" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade15" class="form-control">
                   <option value="">Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          
                        </table>

                        <br>
  </div>

<div class="form2a" id="div2a" name="twositting">

                        <br>
<h4 style="text-align:center; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5%; background-color:#0d4115; width: auto; color: white;"> SECOND SITTING</h4>
<div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>School Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="schoolname2" id="schoolname" class="form-control" placeholder="School Name" required>
                <span id="error_schoolname" class="text-danger"></span>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exam Type</label>
 <select name="examboard2" id="examboard" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value="">Exam Type</option>
                  <option value="WAEC">WAEC(SSCE)</option>
                  <option value="WAEC">WAEC(GCE)</option>
                  <option value="NECO">NECO(SSCE)</option>
                  <option value="NECO">NECO(GCE)</option>
                  <option value="NABTEB">NABTEB(SSCE)</option>
                  <option value="NABTEB">NABTEB(GCE)</option>
                  <option value="OTHERS">OTHERS</option>
                  <span id="error_examboard" class="text-danger"></span>

              </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exam Date</label>
  <?php
  $examyear = range(1960, 2099);
  ?>
   <select class="form-control" name="examdate2" id="examdate" placeholder="Exam Date">
     <option value="">Select date</option>
      <?php
      foreach($examyear as $examdate){
        echo '<option value= "' .$examdate.'">'.$examdate.'</option>';
      }
?>
   <span id="error_examdate" class="text-danger"></span>

   </select>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exam Number</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="examno2" id="examno" placeholder="Exam Number">
   <span id="error_examno" class="text-danger"></span>

  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-borderless" id="example">
            <tr>
              <td width="12%"><label class="control-label">S/NO</label></td>
              <td width="53%"><label class="control-label">SUBJECTS</label></td>
              <td width="35%"><label class="control-label">GRADE</label></td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject21" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade21" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select</option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject22" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade22" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject23" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade23" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>
              <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject24" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>
                
</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade24" class="form-control">
                   <option value=""> Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>
          <?php include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
                <select name="subject25" class="form-control" id="subject">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
    <?php 
    if($count > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<option value = ''>Subject not available</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select name="grade25" class="form-control">
                   <option value="">Select </option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="B3">B3</option>
<option value="C4">C4</option>
<option value="C5">C5</option>
<option value="C6">C6</option>
<option value="D7">D7</option>
<option value="E8">E8</option>
<option value="F9">F9</option>              </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                         
             
                        </table>

</div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
      
  </form>
```

The above is my HTML and JavaScript codes. Am using that JavaScript to display form based on the no of sittings selected.

Below is my PHP code

```
$sitting = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sitting']);
$schoolname1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['schoolname1']);
$examboard1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['examboard1']);
$examdate1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['examdate1']);
$examno1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['examno1']);
$subject11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject11']);
$grade11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade11']);
$subject12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject12']);
$grade12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade12']);
$subject13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject13']);
$grade13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade13']);
$subject14 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject14']);
$grade14 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade14']);
$subject15 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject15']);
$grade15 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade15']);
$schoolname2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['schoolname2']);
$examboard2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['examboard2']);
$examdate2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['examdate2']);
$examno2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['examno2']);
$subject21 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject21']);
$grade21 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade21']);
$subject22 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject22']);
$grade22 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade22']);
$subject23 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject23']);
$grade23 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade23']);
$subject24 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject24']);
$grade24 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade24']);
$subject25 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject25']);
$grade25 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grade25']);


$enter = "INSERT INTO applicants(sitting, schoolname1,  examboard1, 
examdate1, examno1, subject11, grade11, subject12, grade12, subject13, 
grade13, subject14, grade14, subject15, grade15, schoolname2, examboard2, 
examdate2, examno2, subject21, grade21, subject22, grade22, subject23, 
grade23, subject24, grade24, subject25, grade25) VALUES('$sitting', 
'$schoolname1', '$examboard1', '$examdate1', '$examno1', '$subject11', 
'$grade11', '$subject12', '$grade12', '$subject13', '$grade13', 
'$subject14', '$grade14', '$subject15', '$grade15','$schoolname2', 
'$examboard2', '$examdate2', '$examno2', '$subject21', '$grade21', 
'$subject22', '$grade22', '$subject23', '$grade23', '$subject24', 
'$grade24', '$subject25', '$grade25')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $enter);
if($result){
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Details Uploaded !!'); 
</script>";
header('location: success.php');
}else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Details Failed !!');</script>";

}
}
```

Is there any better way to do this without repeating all those subjects and grades?

Comment: ___You could start by___ using a sensible code indentation. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I will try to abide by it. But back to my question, is there any better way to achieve the same result with a short code apart from the one I did above?

Comment: You can loop through form variables instead of hard coding them.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168056/php-loop-through-form-values

Comment: Looping both subjects and grades?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting into a pickle with your form names. PHP makes this a little bit easier by allowing you to specify array names in forms:

```
<?php
if ($_POST)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
<form method="post">
    Grades:
    <input name="grade[]" type="text">
    <input name="grade[]" type="text">
    <input name="grade[]" type="text">

    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This produces this post output, which is easy to loop over:

```
Array
(
    [grade] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

That works for lists of data, but your use-case has an additional dimension, which makes this harder. You have:

- a first-order list containing school name, exam board, exam date, and exam number
- a second-order list belonging to the first one, which contains subjects and grades

However, PHP will support that too, by letting you specify which sub-list the second-order lists belong to:

```
<?php
if ($_POST)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
<form method="post">
    Board: <input name="board[]" type="text">
    Grades:

    <input name="grade[0][]" type="text">
    <input name="grade[0][]" type="text">
    <input name="grade[0][]" type="text">

    <hr>
    Board: <input name="board[]" type="text">
    Grades:

    <input name="grade[1][]" type="text">
    <input name="grade[1][]" type="text">
    <input name="grade[1][]" type="text">
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This produces this arrangement:

```
Array
(
    [board] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [grade] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

You can see here that the 0th entry in `board` is the exam board (first order list) and the 0th entry in `grade` is a list in itself (second order list pertaining to the 0th board).

I will leave it to you as a valuable exercise to add the other elements to the first and second-order lists here.

---

In relation to the table, that is a broad enough topic to merit another question on its own. The structure of this needs to be normalised, so you hold exam boards, exams, students and grades in separate tables. The "grade" is probably the central table, since that requires an exam and a student, and the exam in turn requires a board.